# Drag features out of Openlayers 4 map?

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to find a way to drag features out of an Openlayers 4 map and onto a drop target, but from what I can tell this isn't supported.

I've found that GeoJSON/KML/etc can be dragged *onto* a map, and features can be dragged *within* a map, but none of the Googling I've done or trolling through the OL docs and issues points at any way to drag data all the way out of the map.

I feel like I might have to go with the generic Drag/Drop API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API), but I'm not sure how well that will work with the map element and I'm afraid it would interfere with the normal dragging and rotation of the map itself.